# Is there a connection between the normal and the logistic distribution?

Tags: distributions, logistic, normal-distribution, logistic-distribution

Regarding Bayesian statistics I found in a script that there is such link, and the logistic arises in context of a normal distribution and a "binary state". However, I have no idea what is the meaning behind this. And I found no further hints. The Student-t is highly connected to the confidence interval for mean of a normal distribution, so I wonder if there is something similar regarding the logistic distribution.

Comment: *logistic arises in context of a normal distribution and a "binary state"*: actually, this the probit model, as described in @Xi'an's answer

Answer (score 6):

The only link I can think of is that...

> ...the probit is to the Normal what the logit is to the logistic...

Namely that the [probit regression model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probit_model) where a conditional distribution of a binary variable is defined by
$$\mathbb{P}(Y=1|X) = \Phi(\beta^\text{T}X)$$
and can be interpreted as
$$Y=\mathbb{I}_{Y^*\ge 0}\qquad Y^*|X\sim\mathcal{N}(\beta^\text{T}X,\sigma^2)$$
(interpreted meaning that the latent variable $Y^*$ does not need to exist "for real").
Similarly for the [logit regression model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) where a conditional distribution of a binary variable is defined by
$$\mathbb{P}(Y=1|X) = \dfrac{1}{1+\exp(-\beta^\text{T}X)}$$
which can [be interpreted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#Latent_variable_interpretation) as$$Y=\mathbb{I}_{Y^*\ge 0}\qquad Y^*|X\sim\mathcal{L}(\beta^\text{T}X,\sigma^2)$$
where $\mathcal{L}(\beta^\text{T}X,\sigma^2)$ denotes the logistic distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Without the precise quote and a source we can only guess what the author meant. Are we sure that we are talking about the logistic *distribution*, and not logistic *function*? Because, from your paraphrase

> the logistic arises in context of a normal distribution and a "binary state"

I'd guess the latter. Logistic function arises when you have two normally distributed classes, $A$ and $B$, with an equal variance $\sigma$ and means $\mu_A$ and $\mu_B$, respectively. Then, the posterior probability of an observation with a value $x$ to belong to a class, say, $B$ is given by the logistic function

$$
P(B | x) = \frac{1}{1 + \exp \left(-\beta_0 - \beta_1 x \right) }.
$$

where

$$
\beta_0 = \frac{\mu_A^2 - \mu_B^2} {2 \sigma^2} - \ln \frac{P(A)}{P(B)}
 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ \text{and} ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
\beta_1 = \frac{\mu_B - \mu_A} {\sigma^2}
$$

See [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/467427/169343) for details.